# How do you only map portion of index? reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is my code below

```
I want to only map data upto where index is equal to 10. How do I change my code?
```

My reactjs code looks like below:

```js
{ranks.map((i, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        {index}
    </div>
))}
```

I want to only display my result upto where index is equal to 10

Comment: Using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can filter out conditionally your array before using `.map()` - *The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.* Or using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which states: *The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice()` like so:

`data.slice(10)`

this will return the first 10 items of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ranks.slice(10).map((i, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        {index}
      </div>
    ))}
```